# Can I restart a timer with same timerId after timer_delete()?

Tags: c, linux, timer

I am having problems in restarting timer with same timerId after timer_delete()

Basic structure of my code is as follows:

```
timer_t timerid;/* Global*/

void fun(){
    //Do Something
    timer_delete(timerid);
}

void handler (){
    //Called after timer expiry
    fun();
}

void create_timer(){
    timer_create(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &sev, &timerid);
    timer_settime(timerid, 0, &its, NULL);
    /* timer is 1 second duration one-shot */
}

int main (){
    while (1){
        //wait for user prompt
        if (userPrompt)
        create_timer();
    }
}
```

If you need any more background let me know, I just want to know if I can do this while keeping my timerid global?
The code crashes when I try to start timer for the second time.

Comment: Could'nt you save the time in a variable before deleting it, and just return that value from fun function? And obviously receive that return value and store that too? So you can set the time with that value stored?

Comment: Do you actually need to delete the timer each time? You could create it (but not set its expiry time) before the `while` loop, and set its expiry time whenever you have waited for the use prompt.